# React Navigation Stack Navigator Swipe to Next Screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to have a stack navigator where I can swipe left to start bringing the next screen in the stack on screen on top of the current screen, like [this](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/WKfDs5Hnjsw)

Does React Navigation provide a way to do this? If not, does anyone know of someone who has implemented this functionality?

I tried using a gesture handler and navigating on swipe, but that didn't change the page incrementally with the swipe as shown here. Also, I know I can get similar functionality with a tab navigator with swipeEnabled=true, but that doesn't provide the exact look as this.

Comment: You can always implement a custom navigator: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators.